# How do I create a new directory to hold the assets for a new menu item?

Tags: menus, directory, add-menu-page

I'm a new webmaster, given a WP site to fix.  two menu items on the front page are dead since the code does not href a url.  I also am not yet a full admin since the Dashboard does not offer Appearance and Plugins submenus.  Working on the admin problem.  Do I need to create a directory on the server to hold the assets I will add or does WP take care of that?  Im using Word Press the Missing Manual as my reference.  What book or website do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You need access to Appearances to change the menu. Once in Appearances, click on Menus and create your new menu. Then in the Menu settings select a location (usually primary for the header menu)

[image]

Comment: I do not need to create a NEW menu, my mistake in the initial question, I need to fix a menu item that is not working because the href= statement is missing in the index.php.  How do I edit the index.php?  Does editing the index create the directory that holds the text and picture assets?  If not, how do I create the directory?